# Best way to get Google contact images from Facebook?

Tags: sync, gmail, contacts, facebook

I'm on Android and Syncing my contacts with Gmail/Google contacts.
I don't have a Facebook account.

And lot of my phone contacts are on Facebook where they have a profile ipcture.

Is there any way to sync my contacts and match them against those photos on Facebook based on their phone number?

Comment: Your down vote isn't fair. I have already tried that software, If you read my question I have clearly mentioned that I don't have a Facebook account and that software need one. What I'm looking for is a public search and match.

Comment: You are right of course.  If you don't have a Facebook account there isn't a way to use information contained within a Facebook profile.  You didn't mention you already tried that software, update your question to reflect that fact, and I will remove the downvote.

Comment: If you don't have a Facebook account how do you have contacts on Facebook?

Comment: @slybloty, I Think there is a workround, just needs a coder.
1. Find user id & name: https://graph.facebook.com/nytimes
2. A search on this page with the Name/Username will return their image, publicaly: http://www.facebook.com/search.php?q=jack&init=ffs
3. Parse it and append it to Google Contact.

I'm not aware if Google Contacts API can allow such thing or not, just an idea.

Comment: Are referring to facebook app or facebook account?

Comment: What ever solution that can compare my contact name/phone number to a Facebook users data and get user picture assign it to my contact.